# How to fix missing ReactContextBaseJavaModule symbol?

Tags: react-native, react-native-native-module

I wan't to create a custom native module for my app only - so no lib. Following the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android) it gives me an error:

`import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;`

> Cannot resolve symbol 'ReactContextBaseJavaModule'

- My app's `android/app/build.gradle` includes this line, which is included in all react-native modules I have used so far as well.

  `"com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules`
- My `android/build.gradle`:

  ```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

  buildscript {
      repositories {
          jcenter()
          google()
      }
      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

          // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
          // in the individual module build.gradle files
      }
  }

  allprojects {
      repositories {
          mavenLocal()
          jcenter()
          mavenCentral()
          maven {
              // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
              url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
          }
          maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
          maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Can you add your `android/build.gradle`, just the `allProjects` method?

Comment: @PritishVaidya just added it.

Comment: Yep, the gradle seems fine, I just wanted to check whether maven is added correctly or not.

Comment: @PritishVaidya thx... any ideas what else to check or try?

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps I encountered and used to solve importing all the libraries related to React Native Libraries in the Android Studio:

1. First when I created a brand new react native library project using **react-native-create-library** command, the command generated iOS and Android files.
2. I opened the **android** folder using Android Studio.
3. The gradle build reported some errors and fixed the gradle issue by updating some values in **build.gradle** and **gradle-wrapper.properties**.

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
       maven {
           url 'https://maven.google.com/'
           name 'Google'
       }
   }

   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"

   defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion 16
       targetSdkVersion 22
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
   }
   lintOptions {
       abortOnError false
   }
}

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   maven {
       url 'https://maven.google.com/'
       name 'Google'
   }
}

dependencies {
   compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

4. After adding the above 2 changes, Click **Sync Now** or **Try again**. In this step if it asks to install the build version, please install.
5. Now **Clean and Rebuild** the project, On top status bar of the Android Studio:

   Click **Build** --> **Clean Project**   then

   Click **Build** --> **Rebuild Project**
6. After step **#5**, React Native import errors should disappear and the libraries related to React Native must be imported.

Thanks.